# FTP URL in Windows Explorer under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ftp

Under Windows XP and Windows 7, I used to be able to open an FTP site in Windows Explorer with username and password using the following syntax:

```
ftp://username:password@domain.com/path
```

But this does not work using Windows Explorer under Windows 10. Was this feature disabled under Win 10?

Comment: I'm aware of the security risk of having the password in plain text in this kind of URL. But this is for use in a safe environment.

Comment: My research indicates this functionality is exactly the same in Windows 10, so to be clear, you would do exactly what you would do if you were running Windows 7

Comment: In my case, Windows Explorer gives this error message: (my translation)  
"Windows can't find « ftp://user:password@www.domain.ca/public_html/download ». Check and try again. "

Playing with the password, I suspect that the characters "#" in my passwords would not be supported by Windows Explorer 10 anymore (it was supported before and it is supported by my other file manager Directory Opus). I'll try encoding this character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm moving my previous comment to make it an answer as it solved the issued I raised initially:

I found that the issue was with a character in my password that was supported with Windows 7 but not in Windows 10. After having replaced the "#" in my password with its encoded form "%23", everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

it still works just fine - check your syntax for errors. Tried just now on Windows 10:

[image]

Comment: Just found that the issue is with a character in my password that was supported before but not in Windows 10. After having replaced the "#" with "%23", everything is fine. Thank TomEus and @Ramhound.

Comment: This being said, TomEus, your example did not include the username and password in the URL itself (ftp://username:password@domain.com/path). If it would, the Log On dialog box would not be displayed.